# Date Formatting with Google charts

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api, date-format

I am using the Google analytics Embeded API to request data from Google analytics the hour is returned as a 24 hour clock.   14 = 2 pm,  2 = 2 am

I have embed Google Charts into a customer page but cant seem to figure out why the date won't format properly

> E.g '14' to '2:00 PM' or even "14:00" is fine.

This is the JavaScript that I am using. I have also attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9PEj.png) of the result.

[image]

```
 var dataChart3 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
                metrics: 'ga:sessions',
                dimensions: 'ga:hour',
                'start-date': '1daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday'
            },
            chart: {
                container: 'chart-7-container',
                type: '[LINE][1]',
                options: {
                    width: '100%',
                    curveType: 'function',
                    hAxis: {
                        title: 'Time of Day (Hr)',
                        format: 'h:mm a'
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        title: 'Number of sessions'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: ga:hour is returned as an integer 1 - 23.  You are probably going to have to process it yourself i am not sure JavaScript has a way of reformatting that.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, I'm still finding a way to do this.